# Can I replace Z0607MA with Z0107

Tags: transistors, triac

It is a PCB of an old washing machine (Ariston AVTL83). There are triacs [Z0607MA](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/25730/STMICROELECTRONICS/Z0607MA.html). One of them had burnt. The closest replacement we could find was triac of a different type - [Z0107N](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/25734/STMICROELECTRONICS/Z0107MA/1621/1/Z0107MA.html). Since I am familiar with transistors as a logic device rather than electronics, it is hard to understand the difference from the datasheet. The only easy-to-guess difference between those two is the higher current trigger point (slight change of 20%)- 0107 has 1A, 0607 has it 0.8 A.

Will this replacement damage the PCB?

Comment: Might work. I see that the fusing spec is a little lower on the Z0107N (.35 vs .45.) The design should not get close to either, so while your margin is less it's likely to still work.) The gate power dissipation in the Z0107N almost seems *wrong* to me, given that it is 10 times the older part's value and they are both packaged the same. I think I might be inclined to try it. But I'd want to spend more time comparing the two, first. I guess all I'm saying is that I didn't immediately see any specific "stoppers." Maybe someone with a better eye will do so, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an engineer at St and I can tell you: go for it. The Z01 is a very good way to replace the Z006.

Comment: Can you expand this answer? Like explain about pin compatibility, any voltage differences, or if it's an exact match